# Scrapy + Splash: connection refused

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm learning how to work with scrapy + splash. I've created a project inside with a virtual environment and I'm now doing this tutorial: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash.

I've ran splash with:

```
$ docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

which resulted in:

```
2017-01-12 09:18:50+0000 [-] Log opened.
2017-01-12 09:18:50.225754 [-] Splash version: 2.3
2017-01-12 09:18:50.227033 [-] Qt 5.5.1, PyQt 5.5.1, WebKit 538.1, sip 4.17, Twisted 16.1.1, Lua 5.2
2017-01-12 09:18:50.227201 [-] Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) [GCC 4.8.4]
2017-01-12 09:18:50.227645 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2017-01-12 09:18:50.227882 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2017-01-12 09:18:50.333978 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24']
2017-01-12 09:18:50.438528 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2017-01-12 09:18:50.597573 [-] verbosity=1
2017-01-12 09:18:50.597747 [-] slots=50
2017-01-12 09:18:50.597820 [-] argument_cache_max_entries=500
2017-01-12 09:18:50.598696 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2017-01-12 09:18:50.601924 [-] Site starting on 8050
2017-01-12 09:18:50.602119 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7ff528490be0>
```

When I run the following spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderman'
    domain = ['web']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

Everything works fine; scrapy returns the body html. However, when I try SplashRequest from the tutorial like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderman'
    domain = ['web']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                            args = {'wait':0.5},)

    def parse(self, response):
        response.body
```

I get the following messages in my terminal:

```
File "/Users/username/myVirtualEnvironment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
2017-01-12 11:02:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-12 11:03:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: 
Retrying <GET http://192.168.59.103:8050/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out
```

My guess is that splash causes some connection issues, but I don't know how to fix them. I've added:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25
```

But it doesn't help!

**Q:** Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

EDIT: Changing `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` to `False` doesn't work. Entire console log:

```
$ scrapy crawl spiderman
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: myScrapingProject)
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myScrapingProject', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myScrapingProject.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myScrapingProject.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'}
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-12 11:26:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-12 11:26:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.example.com via http://192.168.59.103:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-01-12 11:27:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-12 11:27:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.example.com via http://192.168.59.103:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-01-12 11:28:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-12 11:29:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.example.com via http://192.168.59.103:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-01-12 11:29:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com via http://192.168.59.103:8050/render.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/myVirtualEnvironment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/Users/username/myVirtualEnvironment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/Users/username/myVirtualEnvironment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-01-12 11:29:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-12 11:29:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1746,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 12, 10, 29, 3, 935527),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 12, 10, 25, 18, 451764)}
2017-01-12 11:29:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

EDIT2: If I run `curl http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.examp‌​le.com%2F` in a new terminal window, I get the following ouput in the terminal window that I used to run splash with:

```
process 1: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/etc/machine-id": No such file or directory
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
2017-01-12 10:48:03.341100 [events] {"path": "/render.html", "load": [0.07, 0.02, 0.0], "fds": 19, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1", "_id": 140690919672912, "method": "GET", "rendertime": 6.497595548629761, "active": 0, "qsize": 0, "maxrss": 83860, "args": {"uid": 140690919672912, "url": "http://www.examp\u200c\u200ble.com/"}, 
"timestamp": 1484218083, "status_code": 200, "user-agent": "curl/7.51.0"}
2017-01-12 10:48:03.343167 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [12/Jan/2017:10:48:02 +0000] "GET /render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.examp\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8ble.com%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 1262 "-" "curl/7.51.0"
```

Comment: Have you installed `scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware` in your Scrapy project settings in `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` like [described in the README](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#configuration)? You can also disable robots.txt handling with `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in your scrapy `settings.py`. You can also check that Splash is up and running by opening the web interface at http://localhost:8050/

Comment: Yeah typo sorry. Ehm, how do I install scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware, I can't find it in the readme file sorry. I think it's installed since I also get the following message: `2017-01-12 11:25:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:  'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware', ` Yes splash is up and running!

Comment: And have you tried disabling robots.txt handling with [`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)? If it still does not work, paste your console logs where you run scrapy crawl (all of it, not just the end with `Retrying <GET http://192.168.59.103:8050/robots.txt>`). And if you see anything in the Splash logs in that other console, you can paste that too.

Comment: @paultrmbrth unfortunately `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=FALSE` doesn't help. Edited; now with entire console log.

Comment: Then I don't know. Can you use curl to test your setup? something like `curl http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F`

Comment: @paultrmbrth `curl http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.examp‌​le.com%2F` returns all the HTML of http://www.example.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132990/discussion-between-paul-trmbrth-and-titusadam).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `SPLASH_URL` must point to the locally running Splash instance, usually running at `http://localhost:8050`,

and not the value used as an example in [scrapy-splash README](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#configuration) -- `http://192.168.59.103:8050` which appear in the error logs:

> ```
> Retrying <GET http://www.example.com via http://192.168.59.103:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times)
> ```

The OP tested `curl http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.examp‌​‌​le.com%2F`, which worked, so the settings should say:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
```

Comment: I still get the problem after changing SPLASH_URL into 'http://localhost:8050' ! are there any other possible reasons for this problem?

Comment: @user345, you may want to open another question on StackOverflow. Did you include 'http://' in your SPLASH_URL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer which helped solve the problem. I wonder though why the scrapy-splash README is not clearer about it (or should it be obvious)?

Answer (score 0):

I had my splash app running in background , so I changed SPLASH_URL from the default on to the one on which my splash app was running , and it worked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qveCg.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The accepted answer already contains this information. Why did you post this new answer?